# Raster Layer Statistics CSV Output using QGIS Graphic Modeller

Tags: qgis, raster, export, csv, qgis-modeler

I am currently working on a project where I am using historical cloud coverage from MODIS Cloud Fraction data to try and estimate future cloud coverage of any particular month. I currently have 10-years worth of data for January through to December and have generated global mean, minimum and maximum raster layers (**Step 1**) for each individual month for that 10-year period. I have detailed the methodology in the flow diagram below to show the steps taken. I currently have 3 layers of global statistics (mean, minimum and maximum) for each month of the 10-year period (**Raster 2**).

As I am doing this is in Graphic Modeller, is there any way that the final output in **Step 4** be written to a CSV file? Conversely, is there a way to script this process (I don't code well) that will make things a bit easier/ more specific if I want to specify output statistics such as minimum, maximum, mean, +1 standard deviation and -1 standard deviation? This is all so that I can display (at least) the minimum, maximum and mean cloud cover from January to December for any given AOI on a graph.

[image: Process Workflow]

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of your question, you could use a **Custom script** in your model to fetch and write the raster statistics to a csv. This would replace your *Step 4. Raster Layer Statistics*.

To do this, go to *Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script* and copy the following (*note: change the path of the `text_file_path`*):

```
##Raster statistics=name
##Layer=raster

import csv
from qgis.core import QgsRasterBandStats

text_file_path = "C:/Users/You/Desktop//result.csv"  # Change path to desired location
layer = processing.getObject(Layer)
provider=layer.dataProvider()
ext = layer.extent()
stats = provider.bandStatistics(1,QgsRasterBandStats.All,ext,0)

with open(text_file_path, 'wb') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Statistic', 'Value']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'Statistic': 'Band_Number', 'Value': stats.bandNumber})
    writer.writerow({'Statistic': 'Mean', 'Value': stats.mean})
    writer.writerow({'Statistic': 'Std_Dev', 'Value': stats.stdDev})
    writer.writerow({'Statistic': 'Sum', 'Value': stats.sum})
    writer.writerow({'Statistic': 'Sum_of_Squares', 'Value': stats.sumOfSquares})
    writer.writerow({'Statistic': 'Minimum', 'Value': stats.minimumValue})
    writer.writerow({'Statistic': 'Maximum', 'Value': stats.maximumValue})
    writer.writerow({'Statistic': 'Range', 'Value': stats.range})
```

Save the script into `C:/Users/You/.qgis2/processing/scripts`.

Then add it to your model using the output of *Step 3.* as the input for the script. I ran a simple model and the result looked like this in the .csv file (using Excel for viewing):

[image: csv result]

---

For the second part of your question, I'm not sure how to obtain plus minus standard deviations separately as these are not mentioned in the [QgsRasterBandStats class](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterBandStats.html).